# Value error: setting an array element with a sequence data preprocessing

Tags: python, matrix, regression, data-processing, csr

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('train_data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(),[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])],remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 10, random_state = 0)
regressor.fit(X, y)                 #Error is thrown here
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'csr_matrix'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just in case there might be no answer popping up soon, the code seems to lack the import statements, so it doesn't seem to be a self contained snippet. If you make it easier for others to run it directly and see the bug locally, where possible, you increase the chance of good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from this `np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))` . From one hot you get a sparse matrix (type csr) and you don't need to put it inside a numpy array again. You can either convert it to dense using:

```
ct.fit_transform(X).todense()
```

But this can be really costly on the memory and unnecessary since the regressor can take a sparse matrix. You can simply pass it in, I illustrate below with an example dataset:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['A','B','C'],(50,13)),
columns=["v"+ str(i) for i in range(13)])
dataset['v14'] = np.random.uniform(0,1,50)
dataset['y'] = np.random.normal(0,1,50)

X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(),
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])],remainder='passthrough')
```

We transform `X` now, keep it as sparse:

```
X = ct.fit_transform(X)
type(X)
scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

Then regress:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 10, random_state = 0)
regressor.fit(X, y)
```

The above will not throw an error